# How to correctly load data on WS event?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios, socket.io

So. Server sends event to every client in specific room on message submit for other clients to load messages, so they can see that new message. React client correctly receives, but loads messages in weird way. It renders page with no messages and after few miliseconds loads correctly. It cause very ugly blink.

Client socket.io code:

```
useEffect(() => {
      loadRooms(userId).then(data => {
        dispatch(setRoomsList(data))
      })
      loadMessages(roomId).then(data => {
        dispatch(setMessageList(data))
      });

      socket.on('receive_message', data => {
        dispatch(addNewMessage({id: data.id, content: data.message, roomId: data.room, userName: data.userName}));
        console.log(messageList)
      })
    }, [dispatch, roomId, socket])
```

Client who sends message doesn't have this bug. On this client, axios request works correctly.

Submit message handler:

```
const handleMessageSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      sendMessage(userName, currentMessage, roomId).then(data => {
        loadMessages(roomId).then(data => {
          dispatch(setMessageList(data))
          socket.emit('send_message', {message: currentMessage, room: roomId});
        })
        setCurrentMessage('')
      })
    }
```

Loading message normally with that handler work just fine, but with socket.io it is bugged.

How messages are displayed in page:

```
{messageList.map(message =>
                    <div sx={{overflow: 'auto'}} key={message.id} style={{display: 'block', width: '70vw', marginTop: '5px', clear: 'both'}}>
                      <div style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'}} key={message.id}>{message.userName}: {message.content}</div>
                    </div>
                  )}
```

**messageList** is redux state, which I get using **mapStateToProps**

Socket.io on the server side:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    let prevRoom = 1;
    console.log("Users's id", socket.id)
    
    socket.on('send_message', (data) => {
        socket.to(data.room).emit('receive_message', data.message)
        console.log("sent", data.message)
    })

    socket.on('join_room', (data) => {
        socket.leave(prevRoom)
        prevRoom = data;
        socket.join(data)
        console.log("joined")
    })
} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind sending data through web sockets is that you read it from message that you receive and then render. You don't do that here. You ignore the data in "receive_message" and call "loadMessages" that, I assume, loads full messages list from api. This extra call to api causes the ugly blink, but the code that resets messageList is not in question (probably in redux).

You need to get rid of extra api call and append the new message received via web socket to your existing message list

Comment: It works very well, but there is one issue.
I made redux action to push data to redux state.
And made event listener on client to push new message to list.
It pushes new message 3 times and three the same messages are displayed.

Comment: I checked it using devtools - socket.io calls dispatch three times.

Comment: Socket.io doesn't call dispatch, you call dispatch when you receive a message via socket.io. So, there are 2 options here - you receive the message 3 times or you have 3 of the same handlers waiting for the message. You can debug this with logs on event handlers both on server and client

Comment: As you can see, I have logs on server side. Server sends message only one time.
I added log to client and it logs new message 3 times.
How can I see how many handlers are waiting for the message?

Comment: You have the code that creates a handler as socket.on('receive_message'... - this code should run only once. You can add console.log("Add message handler"); one line above and you will see how many times it runs

Comment: You probably have it inside react component and not in the mount effect hook, so it runs multiple times when component rerenders. But this is just a wild guess, as I don't see the code:) You can add more code to the question and I'll help you find the bug

Comment: I added some more code and I can't find anymore to show you.
I am pretty sure, that list of react states or bunch of layout code won't help you

Comment: Your effect was running multiple times. Here's the most possible reason - https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93 I am glad you fixed that:)

Comment: Yup, finally fixed.
Everything works.
Thank you so much!
Didn't expect issue from framework side :D